# Get notification when QThreadPool of QRunners in PyQt4 have completed execution

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, pyqt, signals-slots

I've got this quick and dirty test I setup where I'm running a thread of QRunners in a QThreadPool one by one in PyQt4 on Python 2.7. Basically it looks like it's running fine, but the threads/pool don't seem to stop the QThreadPool once all threads have completed execution.

I'm wondering if it's as simple as returning some built in method from the QRunnable (`ProductImporter` here) when it's done executing it's code, but I can't seem to find anything in the documentation.

I'm moving some code over to this setup from a QThread structure, since I can't have concurrent threads running at the same time.

Any ideas on how I could have the ProductImportTasks aware that it's tasks have all completed, so I can execute more code afterwards, or after that class is called? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtCore import QThreadPool, QObject, QRunnable, pyqtSignal

class WorkerSignals(QObject):
    productResult = pyqtSignal(str)

class ProductImporter(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self, product):
        super(ProductImporter, self).__init__()

        self.product = product
        self.signals = WorkerSignals()

    def run(self):
        self.signals.productResult.emit(self.product['name'])
        return

class ProductImportTasks(QObject):
    def __init__(self, products):
        super(ProductImportTasks, self).__init__()
        self.products = products
        self.pool = QThreadPool()
        self.pool.setMaxThreadCount(1)

    def process_result(self, product):
        return

    def start(self):
        for product in self.products:
            worker = ProductImporter(product)
            worker.signals.productResult.connect(view.text)
            self.pool.start(worker)

        self.pool.waitForDone()


class ViewController(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ViewController, self).__init__(parent)

    #@pyqtSlot(str)
    def text(self, message):
        print "This is the view.text method: " + message
        return


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = ViewController()
    main = ProductImportTasks([{"name": "test1"}, {"name": "test2"}, {"name": "test3"}])
    main.start()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what your script does:

1. calls `main.start()`
2. creates runnables and starts threadpool
3. waits for all the runnables to finish
4. returns from `main.start()`
5. starts the application event-loop

Once the event-loop has started, the signals that were emitted by the runnables will be processed, and the messages will be printed. This is because signals sent across thread are *queued* by default. Normally, signals are sent synchronously, and don't require a running event loop.

If you change the connection type of the signals, and add a few print statements, it should be clear what's going on:

```
            worker.signals.productResult.connect(view.text, Qt.DirectConnection)
            self.pool.start(worker)

        self.pool.waitForDone()
        print('finished')
        ...

    main.start()
    print('exec')
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Aha, it looks like it's really all in the signal connection type--- in this case synchronous vs asynchronous. I had to step away from this project for a bit so I'm going to have to sit and review whether or not sync vs. async works in this case, but for now I think this should work, thank you!